# ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I've been working through the "Introduction to Machine Learning with Python" O'Reilly.

when running this block, I'm getting the convergencewarning.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
cancer = load_breast_cancer()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    cancer.data, cancer.target, stratify=cancer.target, random_state=42)
logreg = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Training set score: {:.3f}".format(logreg.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Test set score: {:.3f}".format(logreg.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

I've seen several possible means of working this out, but as I'm really just learning this in general, am not really sure what is required.

[Original author's notebook](https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/blob/master/02-supervised-learning.ipynb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the data you are using is not in a good condition to converge with given algorithm. As you are using Logistic Regression, sklearn's default `max_iter` value is 100.

You can try to scale your data with `StandartScaler`. That's basically getting ready your data for the ML algorithm which can help converging.

Or you can change `max_iter` to see if it will converge or not.

For example:

```
logreg = LogisticRegression(max_iter = 1000).fit(X_train, y_train)
```